# Magento 1.9 - Layered Navigation Links Ending with ?cat= or ?brand=

Tags: magento-1.9, url, seo

I am working on URL issues for a customer of mine and they have subcategory links ending in ?cat= and ?brand=. If I'm not mistaken, this is bad for SEO and not ideal for customer user experience.

I looked up the issue and found that it has to do with is_anchor set to 1/yes. I set all of the categories not to be anchors but this changed the way the left sidebar functioned, which is not what I was hoping for.

I have reindexed and cleared both caches but still have not had any success removing ?cat and ?brand from links.

I have web server rewrites enabled, there is no suffix for category and product pages and I have reindexed/flushed the cache multiple times.

The specific version of Magento is 1.9.2.4 running on PHP 5.6.38 and MySQL 5.5.

What else should I check?

[EDIT] Using the function here: https://www.blueclaw.co.uk/2013/08/12/fix-category-url-filter-in-magento-layered-navigation/, I was able to fix it for ?cat= but when I did it for ?brand, the links didn't quite look right. Presumably because they're brands, rather than categories. Is there a way to fix it for attributes or will I need an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above trick of replacing the category filter by the actual category url works because categories have their own url. Attributes don't, so you're stuck with query parameters. To make matters worse, Magento only shows the database id of each attribute value instead of the value (label) itself.

Changing this behaviour is not trivial. If you really want to change this behaviour, I suggest to look for a Magento module that implements this functionality.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. I fixed the categories at least. I'll hunt for a module. Figured that was the answer.

If you have any module suggestions, especially free ones, let me know.

Comment: I have used a number of commercial modules in the past, but they all have their downsides. I haven't been able to track down a good open source module, although the Flagbit_FilterUrls module looks promising.